# Why is there no Men's T20I cricket at the 2022 Commonwealth Games?

Tags: cricket

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_at_the_2022_Commonwealth_Games):

> The matches are being played as **Women's Twenty20 Internationals (WT20Is)**,
> with only a **women's** tournament being part of the Games.

Why is there no Men's T20I cricket at the Birmingham 2022 Commonwealth Games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Men's team from several countries were [opposed](https://www.insidethegames.biz/articles/1054975/cricket-will-not-be-part-of-2022-commonwealth-games-after-men-turn-down-chance-to-take-part) to inclusion of Men's Cricket as it would coincide with already [scheduled games](https://www.cricschedule.com/year/2022.php). These games were scheduled in advance and maybe postponing isn't feasible from the business side of view and others.

Comment: Fixture congestion in men's cricket is apparently [the subject of ongoing controversy](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/62454761), with several top-level players believing there are too many matches being held. Throwing a Commonwealth Games tournament into the mix would have made things even worse, so it doesn't surprise me that the idea was rejected.